# Issue with Uppercase naming

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a React beginner trying to make my file structure right.

Here is `/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Then I have `/components/App/index.js`

```
export { default } from './App';
```

And finally, `/components/App/App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

I've got the following error while running the app:

```
./src/components/App.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/me/Documents/Dev/Project/client/src/components/App.js'
```

If I rename, the `components/App` folder to `components/app` and update the references accordingly, it works.

Any idea why I can't use Uppercase name for my folders? I've read that React is supposed to accept both naming convention.

Comment: i think your import isn't right , it seems App folder and App.js file but in index you imported App.js without App folder

Answer (score 0):

Your filename is `app.js` and not `App.js`, that is why the import fail when you are trying to import from `App.js`.

You are doing a default export from the app.js file, that means you can basically import the default export the way you like:

e.g.
`import MyApp from './components/app`

Just keep in mind that React Components renders when the first letter is uppercase.
So using the default export the following way would not work:

`import myapp from './components/app`

Note that the extension (.js) is omitted. The default behavior will assume it is in fact a .js file and thus the extension can be omitted in this case.

If you were to import e.g. a css file instead, the extension of the file would indeed need to be provided accordingly.

e.g. `import styles from './css/main.css'`